NextJS build failing with TRPCClientError
this is my first NextJS app and my build keeps failing while compiling the page data. I haven't heard of any build debugging capabilities so I'm doing it the old fashioined way with console.log.
I put a log on every getStaticProps, getServerSideProps, and getStaticPaths in the application. I only have one dynamic page and that is the one that seems to be the problem.
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
    console.log(`getStaticPaths: templateleaf`);
    
    const templates = await DataService.Template.getAllSafe();

    const paths = templates.map((template) => ({
        params: { templateLeaf: template.leaf },
    }));

    console.log(`getStaticPaths: finish templateleaf`);

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: "blocking",
    };
};

The last console.log is triggered but the build fails when moving on to Generating static pages. Here's the error I'm seeing:

getStaticPaths: finish templateleaf


   Collecting page data  ..TRPCClientError: fetch failed
    at TRPCClientError.from (file:///C:/Users/pc/Dev/Projects/eldritch-grove/node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/TRPCClientError-38f9a32a.mjs:38:16)
    at file:///C:/Users/pc/Dev/Projects/eldritch-grove/node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/httpUtils-b9d0cb48.mjs:128:36
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  meta: {},
  shape: undefined,
  data: undefined,
  [cause]: TypeError: fetch failed
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11) 
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    cause: AggregateError
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5) {
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      [errors]: [Array]
    }
  }
}
TRPCClientError: fetch failed
    at TRPCClientError.from (file:///C:/Users/pc/Dev/Projects/eldritch-grove/node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/TRPCClientError-38f9a32a.mjs:38:16)
    at file:///C:/Users/pc/Dev/Projects/eldritch-grove/node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/httpUtils-b9d0cb48.mjs:128:36
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  meta: {},
  shape: undefined,
  data: undefined,
  [cause]: TypeError: fetch failed
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11) 
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    cause: AggregateError
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5) {
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      [errors]: [Array]
    }
  }
}
 ✓ Collecting page data
   Generating static pages (0/8)  [    ]

Running node 18, trpc/next, next 14.2.5.
Any help understanding what's going on would be greatly appreciated. This is holding up my test deployments.

Fixed. It was an issue with trpc (client) accidentally being called in my pages.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
